# An interesting way of partitioning with inner ordered combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, integer-partitions, set-partition

> Assume $ K $ labeled blocks $ s_1, s_2, \dots, s_K $ ($ s_1 < s_2 < \dots < s_K $) that arrive sequentially and need to be accomodated as they arrive in $ N $ containers (partitions with empty containers also matter as shown in the picture. The capacity of the containers is unlimited.). I need to find an expression that gives all the possible combinations of partitions where the order of the elements matters.

[image]

**Some examples:**
$$
\begin{align}
K = 2, N = 1 \rightarrow & [1 ~ 2] \\
K = 2, N = 2 \rightarrow & [-],[1 ~ 2] \\
             & [1 ~ 2],[-] \\
             & [1],[2] \\
             & [2],[1] \\
K = 2, N = 3 \rightarrow & [-],[-],[1 ~ 2] \\ 
                         & [-],[1 ~ 2],[-] \\ 
                         & [1 ~ 2],[-],[-] \\ 
                         & [-],[2],[1] \\
                         & [2],[-],[1] \\ 
                         & [-],[1],[2] \\ 
                         & [2],[1],[-] \\ 
                         & [1],[2],[-] \\ 
                         & [2],[-],[1]  
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think this is just $N^K$. For each of $K$ distinguishable blocks, you have $N$ distinguishable choices where it can go.

Comment: Your suggested solution matches the results I have shown here. But I am not sure if this is just a coincidence. It does not seem to take into account the partitions.

Comment: @JeremyDover Is right. Any incoming block can go in any of the bins, so $N^K$ choices. You could but don't have to count by partition - I think the multinomial coefficients will do that for you.